# Dual UK/Canadian Citizens travelling to USA and Canada

Tags: passports, dual-nationality

We are dual UK/Canadian citizens with both UK and Canadian passports. We reside in the UK. We will be travelling to the USA and Canada on holiday.
Can we:
-  leave UK on our UK passport and enter USA on Canadian pasport, then
-  fly out of USA to Canada using our Canada passport
-  fly back from Canada to UK with "in transit" stop in USA airport, using Canada passport to leave Canada and to get us through the "in transit" bit, and then re-enter UK on UK passport?

Alternative would be to get ESTA forms and to use our UK passports while travelling in USA and "in transit" in the USA

Comment: I'm not marking this question as duplicate since the two specific passports held can be a crucial factor in what passport to use where.

Comment: Why don't you take and present both to immigration officials? Unless one of those countries have problems with another nationality, and AFAIK neither UK nor Canada does.

Answer (score 4):

Your first approach is exactly right, with one slight change.

Your Canadian passport will get you into the US with minimal hassle, and significant advantages at US immigration. Often US immigration will treat Canadian passport holders as equivalent to US passport holders in terms of putting them in fast lanes etc. Using a UK passport will mean you getting a visa waiver and being fingerprinted. Don't even go there.

Your UK passport will get you back into the UK with minimal hassle. You should use it on return. However, on exit from the UK your purpose is to demonstrate to the airline that you are legally allowed to enter the US and Canada. Show the airline your Canadian passport. (You shouldn't be stopped by UK customs on exit, but if you do, show them your British passport). Put your British passport away until you get back to the UK. If your other nationality was one that needed a visa to get into the UK you should show the airline your UK passport on the return flight, but because Canadians can freely enter the UK that isn't an issue - and with an 'in transit' stop in the US the Canadian passport is best for that too.

[Here is an interesting article](http://foxnomad.com/2012/06/07/how-to-travel-with-two-passports-if-youre-a-dual-citizen/).